# A class with 2 names?

Tags: c++

While reading code I came across a class which has 2 identifiers 'naming it':

```
class A_EXP Node
{
//..
};
```

I am not able to understand what this means. Could someone help me out?

Comment: The `A_EXP` is probably a decorator macro of some sort — it likely expands to some compiler-specific construct (visibility controls?) under some circumstances, and to nothing under others.

Comment: `A_EXP` could be a definition for `__dllspec(dllexport)`

Comment: I'd guess it expands to `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 12):

`A_EXP` is probably a macro, possibly expanding to nothing at all.  It may also expand to a `__declspec` or similar declaration, which modifies how the compiler will emit the class as object code.  A common use of this pattern would be:

```
#define A_EXP __declspec(dllexport)
```

Comment: It's fully legal in any compiler for the macro to expand to nothing.